# SharePoint via MS Teams Document Library not handling mandatory columns metadata

Tags: modern

Observe in the following screen shot that there are two blank columns on the right handside: **WBS#** and **Theme Key**

[image]

These should not be blank. I configured them to be mandatory and unique. For example, I configured them by clicking to the document library settings like this:

Settings->SiteContent->Settings (for doc lib) and view the following two screen shots:

[image]

And here you can see that mandatory settings, among other settings. Just showing Theme Key for the example (WBS# is configured the same way).

[image]

Can anyone explain to me how to obtain the behavior associated with the desired configuration? It is as if the SharePoint settings are being ignored.

Note that I am using Microsoft Teams and started this SharePoint site from that tool. It is using the new Modern UI. I am a team/sharepoint owner, but *not* the admin for either MS Teams or Sharepoint. I can contact the admin if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the new configuration when viewed through the modern interface. Required metadata is no longer required on upload, but required only when the properties are edited.

What you're seeing is 'by design'.

Comment: But I don't see anywhere to edit those fields, even when I click on the properties. Is that also by design? Is there any way at all to even enter information in those columns?

Comment: I also turned on the "metadata enterprise" column for this doc lib; and nothing happened. The column did not appear. This is baffling.

Comment: From the SPO interface, yes. On Modern views, it is a slide out panel on the right and it will have an 'Edit all' link to edit the properties. The Files panel in Teams is fairly new and always undergoing changes, so it may not support full fidelity of what you see in SPO.

Comment: I found that slide out. I clicked the "i" info button->in the slide out panel I clicked "edit all" (this is a folder I'm editing-> and the *only* field I can edit is the document (folder) name. No matter how many columns I have, it only displays "name" as an editable field.

Comment: Correct, folders do not have metadata associated with them.

Comment: Okay thank you for the catch up. I'll select this as the answer.

Comment: IMHO this is a horrible change. I am going to ask my admin to switch the entire site back to the "classic" experience. Without being able to tag folders (or any items in a doc list) it breaks what we are trying to achieve with our document management. It's extremely difficult to find any benefit to this new way.

Comment: Folders have never had metadata. Doc Sets do, though (along with metadata push-down). You should look at those.

Comment: I see that for normal files, that it is now saying those fields are required. But for some reason they are not "enforce unique values". This is progress. I also checked out Doc Sets - but it appears to be a feature in the classic experience, only. I now see the enterprise metadata field, too (which I discovered faq using google search term "sharepoint metadata push down faq". Thank you Trevor